# LSP and SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In order to make my code testable, I'm trying to adhere to [Liskov's substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) by having my SwiftUI views depend on protocols rather than concrete types. This allows me to easily swap implementations and allows me to easily build mocks for testing. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```swift
protocol DashboardViewModel: ObservableObject {

  var orders: [Order] { get }
}
```

My `DashboardViewModel` needs to communicate changes back to its dependents, so I've also attached `ObservableObject` as a transitive requirement.

This seems to be a problem. You **cannot** achieve LSP if you have associated type requirements. Here's the error I got from my SwiftUI view class that depended on my view model:

```swift
struct DashboardView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: DashboardViewModel
}
```

> Protocol 'DatastoreProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

I ended up doing this instead:

```swift
protocol DashboardViewModel {

  var orders: [Order] { get }
  var objectWillChange: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> { get }
}
```

This also requires dependents to do additional work to observe for state changes. This takes away the conveniences of using property wrappers - mainly the ability for dependents to observe for state changes using `@ObservedObject`. Using this alternative leads us to code like this:

```swift
struct DashboardView: View {
  let viewModel: DashboardViewModel

  var viewModelSubscriber: AnyCancellable!

  // MARK: - Used only to force a re-render of this view
  @State private var reload = false

  init(viewModel: DashboardViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    viewModelSubscriber = viewModel.objectWillChange.sink { _ in
      self.reload.toggle()
    } 
  }    
}
```

This is a tad distasteful to look at:

1. Created a `@State` variable that is only used to force an update of the view, because we cannot utilize SwiftUI property wrappers to observe for state changes
2. Created a `AnyCancellable!` variable to hold a subscription to `objectWillChange` from the view model. This is necessary to detect state changes from the `DashboardViewModel`
3. Added the subscription call in the initializer that only toggles the `@State` variable to force a retrieval of new data from the view model

I feel like there should be a much better way of handling this. Looking for help!

Comment: Note that protocols don't guarantee that LSP is achieved. You need lots of unit tests to prove that LSP is respected in your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this is to make your view generic:

```
protocol DashboardViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var orders: [Order] { get }
}

struct DashboardView<Model: DashboardViewModel>: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: Model
}
```